# in real networks do servers send request to each other?

Tags: http, server, dns, malware, malware-detection

perhaps a silly question!!
in real networks, do servers send requests to each other? for example do a web server send request to another web server to fetch some data (for example .jpg and so on) ? or can a DNS server send request to another DNS server to ask an ip address? 
i want to implement an algorithm for worm detection. i know servers often listen to a port and answer to the requests. so i think if a server initiate a connection , it is infected. but if in normal condition servers send requests to each other so servers can initiate connection in normal condition and so we can not say a server is infected when it initiate a connection.
thanks.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not directly related to programming. But in all cases it is too vague/too broad. You are mixing various stuff that are completely different. Webservers can act as client and get data from other webservers, they are then called proxy. As for the DNS it does not work the way you think it works, so you need first to read a primer on DNS name resolution to understand it and then come back with more specific questions, after having dome some research, and probably posting more on [su], but read the on-topic part of the help section there.

Comment: "so i think if a server initiate a connection , it is infected." In particular, this is very wrong as written so broadly. Any server is probably a client (hence starting a connection) for DNS data, NTP data, sending emails, sending backups or monitoring data, etc.

Comment: thanks so much for your help dear Patrick Mevzek